# AWS EKS ELK Elasticsearch container running into an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks, elk

While deploying ELK on an EKS cluster, I am running into an error in the pod

kubectl logs pod-name output is following

```
EKS ELK error defaulted container elasticsearch out of: elasticsearch, configure-sysctl (init)
```

kubectl get pod pod-name -w out is following

```
exec /bin/sh exec format error EKS ELK
```

due to which elasticsearch containers are always in the CrashLoopBack. If you can help, I am ready to pay.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but deployment-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you also give us the logs of that pod?

Comment: feel free to post new question with more details like how you are trying to setup ELK using help. also add the more details of logs error and description.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening due to the fact, Elastic-search has two different image tag series
i.e., 8.x.x and 7.x.x
So depending on the CPU type, I was using wrong image.